# Rails - Force model to be created via factory method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-pattern

I'm using Rails 4. I have a class, Cart, which needs to be accessed within my application.

I want it accessed using the factory pattern:

```
class CartFactory
  def self.obtain_cart_for_user(user)
    ...
  end
end
```

I need this approach because sometimes, I want to return an existing cart and sometimes create a new one (based upon the age of the cart, its contents, whether the products in it are still available etc).

This is easy enough.

However, I also want to make sure some other future programmer doesn't instantiate a cart directly, or fetch one by any other means, including via model associations, such as:

```
Cart.new(...)
user.carts.new(...)
Cart.find(id)
Cart.find_by_attribute(blah: blah)
Cart.where(...).first
```

Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: Yes, there's a way to prevent that: don't use Rails, or, more specifically, don't use ActiveRecord.

Comment: I have a feeling you will cause yourself more pain than is worth it, and a determined (or clueless) programmer will easily subvert it anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's possible to [make the constructor private](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1567476/454094):

```
private_class_method :new
```

And of course, you can try making the ActiveRecord query methods (`.find`, `.where` etc.) private as well. But to me that sounds like a good way to end up with erratic behaviour. If you were to go this route, make sure your app is thoroughly tested first.

---

Another route would be for `Cart` not to extend `ActiveRecord::Base` (which I'm assuming it does), and instead include only the parts you need, like `ActiveRecord::Persistence`. If you are willing to dive in deep, check out the parts that are included in [the source for `ActiveRecord::Base`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb).

---

Edit: Still one option would be to make `Cart` itself private within a module that only exposes `CartFactory`. There's no built-in syntax for a "private class", but [it's possible to achieve since Ruby classes are just regular objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3498680/454094). Again, no idea how well ActiveRecord would deal with that.

---

But lastly there is of course the question of whether you want to do this at all. In general, Ruby is not very good at protecting you from yourself. :) As expressed in the latter linked answer, documentation and trust go a long way.

Comment: Making Cart private within a module worked, however I ended up taking the advice and just relying on documentation, trust and a heap of unit tests.